# Heroku - configuring scheduler in app.json

Tags: json, heroku, configuration, scheduler

Is there a way to get the Heroku Scheduler to be configured with

- a script to run
- frequency

Using [app.json addons](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons) configuration, so that it is set up automatically from a Github "Deploy to Heroku" button?  I can get the addon to appear using

```
  "addons": [ "scheduler" ]
```

but it's unclear how to configure the script name and frequency.

Comment: Check [Custom Clock Processes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) on Heroku's website, I believe it to me more inline to what you want to achieve. Tell us if otherwise.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Using a clock process means you need to have two processes constantly running (the clock and the worker). Versus zero persistent processes when using the scheduler addon (the process only runs when it is scheduled).

Comment: @MichaelMior Yes, you're right. I keep hitting that wall on a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your  `Procfile` which can create a separate worker for your application

> web:    node web.js
>
> worker: node worker.js
>
> clock:  node clock.js

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the premise of using Heroku Scheduler, and there are design-level trade offs of either approach.